# How to use Http providers in angular2 GA?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use angular 2 Http service but I am getting

> Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)

Which has this signature

```
 constructor(public http:Http){ }
```

I tracked the problem down to declaring the providers for Http.

[In the angular 2 quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) they say

> In this demo, we register providers by importing other NgModules to our root NgModule.

But I already have

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

So, I understand the providers should be fine.

In the code documentation for file `http.d.ts` I find this:

```
 * import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
```

But when I try to write this, I get that `HTTP_PROVIDERS` does not exist (I guess it is before GA)

The only way I can solve this error is by adding `@Inject(Http)` in the signature.

How can I make it work without adding `@Inject(Http)` in the signature?

This is my systemjs config

```
  <script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            map: {
                '@angular/core': './node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': './node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                '@angular/platform-browser': './node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
                '@angular/compiler': './node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
                '@angular/common': './node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
                '@angular/http': './node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
                '@angular/forms': './node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
                'rxjs': './node_modules/rxjs'
            },
            packages: {
                './app': {
                    defaultExtension: 'ts'
                },
                '@angular/http':{
                    defaultExtension:'ts'
                },
                'rxjs': {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        })

        System.import('./app/main.ts').catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });

    </script>
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

You can see all my code at https://github.com/GuyMograbi/angular2-simple-setup

Comment: Could you add your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @yurzui added `tsconfig.json` and systemjs configuration just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `typescriptOptions` to your systemjs configuration

**index.html**

```
 System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    map: {
    ....
```

See also [angularjs 2.0: Can't inject anything through component constructor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602890/angularjs-2-0-cant-inject-anything-through-component-constructor)

Your `tsconfig.json` isn't used in your configuration. You're transpiling files on the fly. You could take a look at this simple seed project https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs

Comment: Yup.. that's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `HttpModule` to imports in `NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule]
  ...
})
```

No need for `@Inject()` for `Http`.

Ensure you have properly imported (TS imports) everything `Http`, `HttpModule`, ...

Comment: yup. did that.. sorry I will add it to the question. problem still occurs.

Comment: Did you provide the `DataService` somewhere? Where do you inject it?

Comment: I meant the method of injection. sorry.. perhaps my question is not clear. The code snippets are from the article - I don't have a component named DataService. I just tried using Injectable like they show in the post (DataService is from the post) and it is failing with that error.

Comment: I need to see the code that's failing. Seeing "some" code is pointless.

Comment: Does it work if you have `@Injectable()` but `@Inject()` removed?

Comment: I rephrased the question completely thanks to your comments.

Comment: `HTTP_PROVIDERS` were replaced by `HttpModule`. Besides that this usually just works. I have no idea why it doesn't for you on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Completely rewriting my answer to be better targeted.

Your module:

```
import {...} from '@angular/...';

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [..., HttpModule],
    declarations: [...],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Your component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `...`
})
export class AppComponent{

    constructor(private http: Http){
    }

    private getMyData(){
        return this.http.get(...)
            .map(...)
            .subscribe(...);
    }
}
```

That should be all you need. There is no `@Injectable` decorator on the AppComponent because it's a `@Component`, it's not an injectable service.

Angular takes care of injecting for you, so you shouldn't need to do any kind of `@Inject(Http)` anywhere.

Only your own services that you create that you want components (or other services) to use should be created as `@Injectable`. E.g.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService{
    doSomething(){
        //...
    }
}
```

You would add that `SomeService` to either your `Module` level providers array (for app-level singleton) or even your `Component`'s own providers array (for new instances along with the components).

```
import {SomeService} from './some.service';

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    template: '...',
    providers: [SomeService]
})
export class SomeComponent{ 
    constructor(private someService: SomeService){
        // someService is a new instance of SomeService (not a singleton)
    }
}
```

Notice, though, that there's no additional `@Inject` code - the providers (either module level or component level, depending on your needs), deal with creating an instance for you, and passing it to the constructor.

Edit to respond to the updated question:

I think your `systemjs.config` might be wrong. I see your app pointing to a ts file instead of js. Browsers don't really run ts, ts needs compiling (transpiling - pick your term of choice) into js. The js is what systemjs.config should be loading, not the ts.

```
packages: {
    app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to inject http directly to my appComponent which is annotated with `@Component` and I get an error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I updated the question to make it clean. I do not have DataService - it is a code snippet from the article demonstrating 2 ways of injecting http. One works, the other does not.. how can I make the other one (@Injectable) work as well?

Comment: @guymograbi Which article are you following? Are using the release v2.0.x? Why exactly are you trying to inject the services yourself instead of leaving it to Angular to do it for you? Your question still shows you using an `@Injectable` decorator in the `AppComponent`. It is not injectable, it is a `@Component`. The Http is (under the hood) `@Injectable`, whereas your `AppComponent` is not.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that up! I did miss the fact that @injectable should be on the service and not the component. So according to your comment, all I need is to use is `@Component` - but when I do this, I get `(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)` - which lead me to the article I link in my question.

Comment: so my question might be like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35371225/1068746

Comment: but I still can't make it to work properly. I would like to make it work without `@Inject`. update the question to focus on the correct problem. thanks!

Comment: @guymograbi Seems as though it's your TS compiling issue like you linked.. Updating my answer to include a snippet from my own systemjs.config - yours I think might be wrong.

Comment: nope - that is actually the correct configuration. I think it is something about providers.. can't put my finger on it.. I think the providers should be registered once I add `HttpModule` to `imports`.

Comment: I rephrased the question completely thanks to your comments.