# When is @Inject optional in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple service in Angular

```
// service.ts
export class SimpleService {
    // ...
}

// component.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'components/mycomp/mycomp.html',
    providers: [
        SimpleService
    ]
})
class MyComponent {
    constructor(private ss: SimpleService) {}
}
```

This above code never works. I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: (?).`

However, if I change my constructor definition to:

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(SimpleService) private ss: SimpleService) {}
}
```

Then it works. Even documentation doesn't seem to use `@Inject`. From the documentation I understand that `@Inject` is explicitly required when my provider token is not class; like, trying to inject primitive values, or using opaque tokens, etc.

Also, I am confused in regards to typescript. [Official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Inject-decorator.html) clearly mentions that when `@Inject()` is not present, Injector will use the type annotation of the parameter. **If type information is erased during typescript transpilation and DI is happening when app is running, how can Angular use type annotation at runtime? Is there anything I am missing?**

Comment: did you add the service as a provider to the component

Comment: Well preferably that would be the scoped `NgModule` that includes the component in declarations. But the point is unless the `@Injectable` service is registered as a `provider` somewhere then it will not be available without an explicit reference.

Comment: @sachilaranawaka yes, I tried both NgModule and providers for component

Comment: @NeilLunn, you are suggesting if I should try adding `@Injectable` as provider in my module. I don't see it anywhere documented.

Comment: Show us your tsconfig.json

Comment: show the full `@Component({...})`

Comment: @yurzui Here is the tsconfig.json

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],

        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}`

Comment: You have the ability to [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44104517/edit)  your question. Please stop posting additional details in comments and make "edits" to your question instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602890/angularjs-2-0-cant-inject-anything-through-component-constructor/39608530#39608530

Comment: @yurzui That did the trick. My `tsconfig.json` was missing `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

to your `tsconfig.json`

See also

- [angularjs 2.0: Can't inject anything through component constructor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602890/angularjs-2-0-cant-inject-anything-through-component-constructor)